# emacs-auctex refuses to open .tex-files

Tags: emacs, tex, auctex

After installing `emacs 28.1` and `auctex 13.1` I can't open `.tex`-files any longer.

If I enter in emacs `Ctrl-x -f Blau-2022-03-20.tex` I get

```
 Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-type-argument arrayp nil)
 replace-regexp-in-string("\[ \\11\\15\\n%\]" "" nil)
 LaTeX-xparse-macro-parse(mac)
 LaTeX-xparse-auto-cleanup()
 run-hooks(TeX-auto-cleanup-hook)
 TeX-auto-parse()
 run-hooks(TeX-update-style-hook)
 TeX-update-style(t)
 
 #f(compiled-function () #\<bytecode -0x12260f12797895d8\>)()
 run-hooks(find-file-hook)
 after-find-file(nil t)
 find-file-noselect-1(#\<buffer Blau-2022-03-20.tex\> "\~/Desktop/Eigene Dokumente/Briefe/Blau-    2022-03-20...." nil nil "\~/Desktop/Eigene Dokumente/Briefe/Blau-2022-03-20...." (790801 2051))
 find-file-noselect("\~/Desktop/Eigene Dokumente/Briefe/Blau-2022-03-20...." nil nil t)
 find-file("\~/Desktop/Eigene Dokumente/Briefe/Blau-2022-03-20...." t)
 funcall-interactively(find-file "\~/Desktop/Eigene Dokumente/Briefe/Blau-2022-03-20...." t)
 call-interactively(find-file nil nil)
 command-execute(find-file)
```

an can't open the file at all. If I click on the four dots, `.tex` appears.

BTW: It works with `.tex~`-files.

I have no idea what I could try, it worked for decades...

The question has been asked since 2014, but all solutions I found didn't work for me.

PS: It works if I enter `myfile.tex` for a second time. So after `Ctr-x -f myfile.tex` I get the strange message, but after another `Ctr-x -f myfile.tex` I can open the file as usual.

Comment: The discussion at https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-auctex/2021-12/msg00009.html may help.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem which drove me to distraction.

In the end, I discovered that the error message was misleading. I'm using a Mac and the file was in a MS OneDrive folder. I didn't have a local copy of the file and I didn't have OneDrive running. When I realised the problem after much wasting of time, I turned on OneDrive and had exactly the symptom you had -- first time, I got the error message, and second time it worked. My hypothesis is that the first time I did this, the file was not there hence the error message, but it prompted download of the file, and by the second time the file was stored locally and it worked.

Comment: Just to follow up. I've just had the same issue with a file on Google Drive that was not cached locally. I got the "wrong-type-argument arrayp nil" error and when I tried again 20 seconds later there was no problem. It seems then that emacs tries to open the file but something goes wrong because there's a time-out on disk.